# Get Only Names Of All Namespaces Kubectl - Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to get a list of the names of all namespaces in a Kubernetes cluster using a kubectl command.

Currently, I am running the below kubectl command which gives me a list of all namespaces.

However, I don't want to see the 'ACTIVE' and 'AGE' columns. I just want the NAME column.

The reason behind this is so that I can add all of the items from the NAME column into an array for further processing.

```
> kubectl get namespaces
NAME                      STATUS   AGE
dread-gorge               Active   284d
dread-lagoon              Active   210d
carncier-basin            Active   164d
chantague-shallows        Active   164d
hilraine-loch             Active   311d
stangrave-waters          Active   271d
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[using jsonpath from kubectl cheatsheet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/)

```
kubectl get ns -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name}{"\n"}{end}'
default
gitlab-runner
kube-node-lease
kube-public
kube-system
```

Answer (score 16):

**Solution-1:**

Here is an alternate way:

```
 kubectl get ns  --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"
```

> -o=custom-columns=  Print a table using a comma separated list of custom columns

**Solution-2:**

Another way of getting the name ***with the type of resource***:

```
kubectl get ns -o name
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative if you would like to use go-templating.  Unfortunately, when I've used the command in Windows, you need to escape the double quotes (").

Linux:

```
kubectl get namespace -o 'go-template={{range .items}}{{ .metadata.name }}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'
```

Windows:

```
kubectl get namespace -o 'go-template={{range .items}}{{ .metadata.name }}{{\"\n\"}}{{end}}'
```

There's also a reference of other output styles available here: https://gist.github.com/hungbang/90b8d71bc659bafb0c96d73144d51c19